# Git modifying line endings on binary files

Tags: git, version-control, automation

I have git running in the default setup and would like to change the configuration so that neither the client or server instances of git make any changes to the line endings.

Currently, there is not a gitattributes file in the repo and the client shows the following output:

```
>> git config --get core.autocrlf
true
```

What is the recommended way to make sure that both the client and server respect the original line endings and do not make any modifications? Please note that the repo contains both binary and text files.

Any recommendations are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Is the server GitHub or Bitbucket?

Comment: Azure Devops GIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, make sure to have `git config --get core.autocrlf` set to `false`: that will avoid Git itself to change eol.

Second, set a [`.gitattributes` file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) with [`eol=lf` directives](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_effects) for the files you want (that will exclude the binaries)

Comment: Is there a scripted way that I can discover which files are text vs binary and populate the .gitattributes file accordingly?

Comment: @nuprap This is generally done by extension: `*.txt eol=lf`, leaving the rest alone. No need to specify binaries, since `git config --get core.autocrlf` is set to false and they are not listed in the `.gitattributes`: they won't be modified.